# MacOS [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)

Tags: mongodb

I want to try mongodb replica set. I follow the steps of《MongoDB: The Definitive Guide》.

```
$ mongo --nodb
```

then in the mongo shell:

```
replicaSet = new ReplicaSet({nodes: 3})
replicaSet.startSet()
```

then terminal repeat to output this:

```
[rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
```

what' the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to do

```
rs.initiate()
```

You could also try like this

```
replicaSet.startSet();replicaSet.initiate()
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/

> Initiates a replica set. Optionally takes a configuration argument in the form of a document that holds the configuration of a replica set.

Comment: that's a good idea to write two statements in one line. I resolved it. Thank you.

Comment: Please DONT run rs.initiate() on new replica when you adding it to the main cluster.